# WinSCP to create an SSH tunnel to connect to a remote MySQL server

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty, tunnel, winscp

I am using **PuTTY** to connect to **remote MySQL server** via SSH tunnel. I will be specifying the source port and destination port and I will be using source port on **MySQL Workbench** to connect to remote MySQL server.

[image]

Is there similar feature on the WinSCP?

**I want to to setup a tunnel on WinSCP, so that I can use it in MySQL workbench.** I tried tunnel option on the connection menu, it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to use WinSCP for this?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Just to know, Whether WinSCP has that kind of functionality.

Comment: You can add a custom command for this though. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [WinSCP connection tunneling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tunneling) function is to connect to an SSH server that is accessible via another SSH server only.

Hence it tunnels only port 22. You cannot use it to tunnel any other port (MySQL).

---

Though if you ask because you have WinSCP opened more frequently than PuTTY, you can at least add a quick button/command to open the tunnel (e.g. using the [Plink tool](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)).

Just add a local [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command) like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh !U@!@ -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

You can actually even use the PuTTY itself (`putty.exe`), if you want to make use of the opened session (remove the `-N` switch).